# Regex select words longer than 4 characters but only one instance if duplicates

Tags: regex, grep, adobe-indesign, grep-indesign

I am trying to format text in InDesign using GREP Style.
The goal is to select words longer then 4 letters in a paragraph but if the word has been duplicated in a paragraph it should not select more then first instance of this word.
This is sample text:

*"The Lord's right hand is lifted high; the Lord's right hand has done mighty things!"*
The solution should give

- Lord right hand lifted high done mighty things

i have done the first part

```
[[:word:]]{4,}
```

but don't have a clue how to deal with those duplicates.

Answer (score 5):

Is order a requirement? If not, how about words longer than 4 characters not followed by that same word later in the text? See:

```
([[:word:]]{4,})(?!.*\1)
```

https://regex101.com/r/Ug4dLZ/1

Result: lifted high Lord right hand done many things

To be more comprehensive, include word breaks (i.e. count "Person" and "Personhood" as 2 separate words):

```
([[:word:]]{4,})(?!.*\b\1\b)
```